# Mathematical calculation in sql(oracle 11g)

Tags: sql, oracle11g

i got a table like:

```
COST    RETAIL  DISCOUNT    CATEGORY
18.75   30.95               FITNESS
14.2    22                  FAMILY LIFE
37.8    59.95   3           CHILDREN
31.4    55.95               COMPUTER
12.5    19.95               COOKING
47.25   75.95   3.8         COMPUTER
21.8    25                  COMPUTER
37.9    54.5                COMPUTER
48     89.95    4.5         FAMILY LIFE
19     28.75                COOKING
5.32    8.95                CHILDREN
17.85   29.95   1.5         SELF HELP
15.4    31.95               BUSINESS
21.85   39.95               LITERATURE
```

And my problem is:
Display the book Category and the average retail price after discount in all categories where average discounted price is less than the highest average retail price of books for all the categories.

I tried with the following query but cant get the solution as i think i did not understood the question properly.

```
select category, retail-discount as A,  avg(A) as B, avg(retail) as C from books 
where B<max(C)
```

Comment: All such average discounted prices would be less than the highest average retail price... so I don't understand what this filter-condition is about. Can you provide the expected output? NB: your SQL statement has invalid syntax (there is no `from` clause), secondly, aggregations are not allowed in `where` clauses, so it could not even run.

Comment: thats where i am stucked in this question. i believe the question has asked for each categories we have to calculate the average retail price after discount means substraction of discount from retail and find out average of that and finally show that discounted price is less than the highest average retail price of books

Comment: Your comment does not really clarify the issue. Please provide the expected output (in your question) for the data you have given.